# Solving differential equation $y''( \frac{1}{x} )+\frac{1}{x}=t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve differential equation
$$y''\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)+\frac{1}{x}=t$$

Where $t\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: what is the derivation from? based on x or based on t?

Comment: Usually $y"(u)$ denotes the second deivative wrt $u$. In that case put $u=1/x)$ and solve for $u$. Then $x(t)=1/u(t)$

Comment: @Arashium $t$ is the constant

Comment: @Urgje $y''(\frac{1}{x})$ denotes the second derivative of $y(x)$ at $1/x$

Comment: Yes, that is what I remarked. $y'' (1/x)=d{^2}/d{u^2}y(u)$  taken at $u=1/x)$.

Comment: That is not what the double prime usually means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put
$$g(x):=y\left({1\over x}\right)\qquad(x>0)\ .$$
Then
$$g'(x)=y'\left({1\over x}\right)\cdot\left(-{1\over x^2}\right),\quad g''(x)=y''\left({1\over x}\right)\cdot{1\over x^4}+y'\left({1\over x}\right)\cdot{2\over x^3}\ .\tag{1}$$
Plugging in $y''\left({1\over x}\right)$ from the given differential equation and $y'\left({1\over x}\right)$ from the first equation $(1)$ we obtain
$$g''(x)=\left(a-{1\over x}\right){1\over x^4}-{2\over x}g'(x)\ .$$
Multiply by $x^2$, and obtain
$$\bigl(x^2g'(x)\bigr)'=x^2 g''(x)+2x g'(x)={a\over x^2}-{1\over x^3}\ .$$
This can be integrated to
$$x^2 g'(x)=-{a\over x}+{1\over 2 x^2}+C\ ,$$
and one more integration finally gives $g$.